# Loop thru each anchor and onclick display an image in modal box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have dynamically generated div's whose content contains an anchor link and path to an image.

I also have a modal box with an image tag in.

What I am trying to do is onclick of the anchor link, set the image tag path which is in the modal box.

Currently what my code does is no matter what anchor link I click, its always setting image path to the first path link.

Here is my JSFiddle link

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pepin/0dmc9rvt/18/)

My Code:

```
            <div id="coupon-listing-items" class="shopping-listings listings">

    <div class="left-split">
     <a class="ads-links" title="Test Title One" href="http://www.test.com/"><h2>Test Title One</h2></a><div class="coupon-text">(Get 20% of by staying 2 nights)</div>
    <span id="sLink" class="hide">http://via.placeholder.com/350x250</span>
    </div>

        <div class="left-split">
     <a class="ads-links" title="Test Title Two" href="http://www.test.com/"><h2>Test Title Two</h2></a><div class="coupon-text"></div>
    <span id="sLink" class="hide">http://via.placeholder.com/400x350</span>
    </div> 

    </div>

    <!-- Modal Box -->
  <div class="modal CouponModal">
  <span class="close-modal">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">
  <input type="button" class="btnprint" name="btnprint" value="Print This Coupon" onclick="PrintC('cp-image')"/>
  <div id="cp-image">
    <img id="coupon-image" />
    <div id="caption">
    <span class="vist">Visit the website: <a id="c-weblink"></a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(".ads-links").each(function(index){

    $(".ads-links").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); var imgsrc = document.getElementById('sLink')   
       $(".CouponModal").css('display', 'block'); 
       $("#coupon-image").attr('src',imgsrc.innerHTML);

    }); 
    $(".close-modal").click(function(e) { 
      $(".CouponModal").css('display', 'none');     
    });

});
```

If you click on Test title one, you will image name 350x250 displayed in the modal box, and if you close the modal box and now click on test title two, instead displaying the image 450x350 just displays the first image.

What am I missing?

Thanks and appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting the first `sLink` no matter which is anchor is clicked.

```
var imgsrc = document.getElementById('sLink');
```

Instead you need to base this on the sLink closest to the anchor clicked.

```
var imgsrc = $(this).parent().find('#sLink')[0];  
//This goes up a level and finds the sLink that is in that same parent//
```

**Note**

- that an ID should be unique and is likely causing part of your confusion, in this case a class might be just as useful.
- your outer loop is superfluous and might cause you trouble down the road.

Updated Your Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0dmc9rvt/25/

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".ads-links").each(function(index) {

    $(this).on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        debugger;
        $(".CouponModal").css('display', 'block');
        $("#coupon-image").attr('src', $(this).parent().find('.sLink').html());

    });
    $(".close-modal").click(function(e) {
        $(".CouponModal").css('display', 'none');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="coupon-listing-items" class="shopping-listings listings">
  <div class="left-split">
    <a class="ads-links" title="Test Title One" href="http://www.test.com/">
      <h2>Test Title One</h2>
    </a>
    <div class="coupon-text">(Get 20% of by staying 2 nights)</div>
    <span class="hide sLink">http://via.placeholder.com/350x250</span>
  </div>
  <div class="left-split">
    <a class="ads-links" title="Test Title Two" href="http://www.test.com/">
      <h2>Test Title Two</h2>
    </a>
    <div class="coupon-text"></div>
    <span class="hide sLink">http://via.placeholder.com/400x350</span>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Box -->
<div class="modal CouponModal">
  <span class="close-modal">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <input type="button" class="btnprint" name="btnprint" value="Print This Coupon" onclick="PrintC('cp-image')"/>
    <div id="cp-image">
      <img id="coupon-image" />
      <div id="caption">
        <span class="vist">Visit the website: <a id="c-weblink"></a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```